# Where can I buy high current smps transformers?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I am designing a 48V/30A power supply from 230VAC using 2 switch forward topology, I am in need of a transformer for this purpose, I have searched all the possible websites for it(DigiKey, Mouser, Coilcraft, Würth Elektronik etc) but was not able to find any. Is winding my own coil the only option or there are sellers who sell high power transformers?

Comment: You might be able to find a suitable transformer from Pulse; they do a lot of high-current planar transformers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, switchmode transformers are custom made for a given manufacturer and product. If you are making a single unit, your best bet is to buy a product that already does what you want (48V/30 A power supply from 230 VAC) and pull the transformer from it.

(Then, again, if you do buy such a power supply, what would be the point of designing your own?)

Comment: Thanks Davide for your answer, but this is a freelance project, so iam providing the client the neccesary BOM, so i cannot be asking him to wind the transformer as he has no experience what so ever, and ofcourse i cannot ask him to buy a supply and savage the transformer from it...! I just wanted a transformer which is near my requirements.

Comment: Hello Ashiq, I would try to help you further, but I am not allowed to because others have locked this question. I suggest you start a new question and don't ask about procurement (against the rules). Instead, ask about design (OK by the rules).